# Print admin toolbar icon in custom module

Tags: 8

How can I print the admin toolbar icon for my module?

I created a module and it has a menu in the admin toolbar. I want to show an icon (module/costum_module/image/00/icon.svg) in this path for my admin toolbar tab.

I created a CSS style for that, but it doesn't work.

Module path :

/module/my module/css/styles.css   =>

```
.toolbar-icon-mymodule-list:before {
    background-image: url(../icons/787878/icon.svg);
}
.toolbar-icon-mymodule-list:active:before,
.toolbar-icon-mymodule-list.active:before {
    background-image: url(../icons/000000/icon.svg);
}
```

/module/my module/mymodule.libraries.yml   =>

```
mymodule.styles:
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.css: {}
```

Comment: You did not tell what you've tried and why it is not working. You can use the css from the toolbar module as example: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/toolbar/css/toolbar.icons.theme.css

Comment: I take that @4k4 also means you aren't showing the CSS styles you added, and you aren't telling us how you added them.

Comment: I edit my question .

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add svg icon for your menu link item in admin toolbar, you have to alter toolbart.

In your mymodule.libraries.yml file

`toolbar:
  version: VERSION
  css:
   theme:
    css/styles.css: {}`

And you need to implement hook_toolbar_alter() in your mymodul.module

```
function mymodule_toolbar_alter(&$items) {
  $items['administration']['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/toolbar';
}
```